# What is the meaning of high/low KL divergance between two distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, computer-science, divergence-theorem

In the available resources on the internet, it is said that KL divergence measures the similarity between two distributions.
But if you use the TensorFlow built-in method to compute the KL divergence between two similar Normal distributions, it gives you a large number. why is that?

I used the formula below:

```
kl = tf.keras.losses.KLDivergence()  # Define KL divergence
tfd = tfp.distributions   
dist = tfd.Normal(loc=0., scale=1.)  # Build a Normal distribution
kl(dist.sample([300000]), dist.sample([300000]))  # Compute the KL between two identical distribution

output:
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=772134.5>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, what you are computing here is not the KL divergence between two 1-dimensional empirical distributions sampled from a normal distribution. You are computing the KL divergence between two 300000-dimensional distributions with each coordinates' probability sampled from a normal distribution (not sure what happens with negative values tbh).  See here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/KLDivergence.